# How to display all contacts to layout without pressing any button

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am new to android and especially to sqlite so please bear with me.

I want to ask, how can I retrieve all the data from android DB and display them to android layout without pressing any button?

Here is my code from the database class:

```
 // Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setTime(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

but I am not sure how to get this list view to my MainActivity, what I have done is something like this:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);


    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursor(MainActivity.this, DB.getAllContacts());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Which of course gives error because I am calling a non-static method from a static context.
How should I call GetAllContacts from my MainActivity?

**edit:**

Here is my CustomCursorAdapter

```
public class CustomCursor extends CursorAdapter {

public CustomCursor(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonPIN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_pin);
    textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do this :

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);

ArrayList<Contact> mList = new ArrayList<>();
mList = DB.getAllContacts();
```

then

```
customAdapter = new CustomCursor(MainActivity.this, mList);
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Also make sure `DB`is a DAO object as seen [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

EDIT:

Here is an example of a base adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private static class Holder {
    ImageView img; // whatever you have here
    TextView tv;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder = new Holder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_here, parent, false);

        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.someid);
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }



//post your code here whatever you want to show


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It gives me the same error because I use non-static method from a static context

Comment: Try doing this without the Handler() ; I  don't know why would you need it.

Comment: I gives me even more errors, but the I don't think the problem is with the handler it's here: `mList = DB.getAllContacts();` and it says what I've written you above about the static. Regarding the DAO I don't know exactly what it is but I don't think it is necessary here, thanks for trying though

Comment: before you DB.getAllContacts(); did you instantiate it like -> DB = new DatabaseClass(this); //context

Comment: Yes but I had made a typo, now I only have this error: where I should have put `android.database.Cursor` I have `java.Uti.ArrayList<com..activityhelp>` in this line `customAdapter = new CustomCursor(MainActivity.this, mList);`. Also I think I must make my `List getAllContact` to `ArrayList getAllContact`

Comment: If you're using a CursorAdapter your second parameter should be a cursor not a list

Comment: Yeah, I did get that but I don't know how to correct it :p

Comment: check my EDIT answer ; for a simple example

Comment: Sorry that I got you to the trouble of posting an example, here is mine

Comment: Well in that case all you need to do is change getAllContacts from Array list to cursor and in your function : after Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);  put cursor.moveToFirst(); then simply return it; hope this works

Comment: Try taking a look at that link that i gave you that guy gives clear explanation about how a database should be created . So you don't have any doubts , i think you must be doing something wrong

Comment: I guess I have made more mistakes because when i ran it crashed and said _id column does not exist line 14 in CustomCursorAdapter, but thanks for helping me, (I fixed the error with the static)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why using Handler. in `MainActivity` you just need to do this:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
customAdapter = new CustomCursor(MainActivity.this, DB.getAllContacts());
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

`getAllContacts()` must be defined **`static`** if you want to access it from `DB` directly, otherwise you can create instance of `DB`

Comment: If I make the getAllContact() static I get this error `java.Uti.List<com..Database>`